# Generating multiple rows in the same table from the same object structure

Tags: c#, .net, xml, entity-framework, ef-code-first

In short, I am trying to take XML data and store it in a table.  The structure giving me problems currently looks like so:

```
<Event>
  <PhaseOne>...</PhaseOne>
  <PhaseTwo>...</PhaseTwo>
  <PhaseThree>...</PhaseThree>
  <EventID>12345</EventID>
  <EventDate>09/09/09</EventDate>
</Event>
```

The end result from this is **3 rows in my Event table** (one for each `<Phase>`).  Each row not only requires the data inside the respective `<Phase>` element, it also requires parent level values such as `<EventID>`.

I have the `XSD.exe` generated classes to deserialize the XML into but I'm at a loss at how to configure my EF Code First Mappings to generate the correct results.

I thought I would simply map each `<Phase>` class to the same table but then I'm not sure how I would map the parent level values (`<EventID>`) to columns in that row.

Unfortunately I cannot change the XML or the table schemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My solution**

I added copies of the `EventID` and `EventDate` members to each `Phase` class and then populated them manually post-deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need to separate your deserialized type and your persisted type - they cannot be the same because your persisted type needs different structure then deserialized type have. You will not be able to set the mapping for your deserialized type because EF doesn't support what you want. Your choices are:

- Create separate types for persistence and fill them from deserialized types
- Don't use deserialization (or write your own) and instead process XML manually with either `XmlDocument`, `XmlReader` or `XElement`. Fill your persisted types directly from read XML
- Don't use EF and persist your deserialized types with stored procedures

Comment: You're right that all of your suggestions are obvious.  I was looking for clarification on being able to access higher level values within my child classes through the EF Mappings.  At the least I can add these structures in with `[XmlIgnore]` and populate them manually post-deserialization which is the more logical option.

Comment: Yes that will be the fourth option I didn't think about.